# Converting HTML to Joomla template

Tags: joomla3.0

I did my template, that include next files:

```
styles.css
index.php
index.html
images
templateDetails.xml
```

Uploaded zip file(that include all this files) to joomla 3.2 and instead my template I see just blank page, with no content or style. What I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: This is because of some wrong PHP code usage in your template's index.php file.

Like, you are trying to access a function which does not exists.

These types of errors rising this issue.

Comment: please display your code from the index.php file

Comment: I found mistake, in php file I didn't close some function so it doesn't work.